# Sphere not moving in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm stuck with this one for quite some time now. I am trying to create spheres via script and update their position based on the position of points. Their position is updating on the `Debug.Log()` but they are not moving in Game View.

Here is my code:

```
void createSpheres(int objCount, float xPointsPos, float yPointsPos){
        var sphereCreator = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);

        sphereCreator.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
        sphereCreator.transform.position = new Vector3(xPointsPos, yPointsPos, 0);
        sphereCreator.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        sphereCreator.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
        sphereCreator.AddComponent<SphereCollider>();

        //ADD THE SPHERES TO THE SPHERELIST
        sphereList = new List<Sphere>();
        for(int loop = 0; loop < objCount-1; loop++){
            Sphere temp = new Sphere();
            temp.sphereName = "sphere"+sphereNameCount;
            temp.sphereObj = sphereCreator;
            temp.sphereXPos = xPointsPos;
            temp.sphereYPos = yPointsPos;

            sphereList.Add(temp);
        }
        sphereNameCount++;
    }

    void UpdateSpheres()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < sphereList.Count - 1; i++){
            sphereList[i].sphereXPos = points[i].position.x;
            sphereList[i].sphereYPos = points[i].position.y;

            Debug.Log($"{sphereList[i].sphereXPos}" + " -- " + $"{points[i].position.x}");
        }
         
    }

    public class Sphere{
        public string sphereName;
        public float sphereXPos;
        public float sphereYPos;
        public GameObject sphereObj;
    }
```

The `createSpheres()` method is called inside a loop containing how many points are spawned to match it.

I also tried checking if the `ArrayList` is empty or not using `Debug.Log()` and it returned all the Sphere gameObjects that I added.

Any help or hint will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are your calling your UpdateSpheres() function? can't see it in your script

Comment: @MuhammadFarhanAqeel Yes, it's being called in FixedUpdate() method

Comment: Are you sure the list of objects has values in it? In your first function you are looping from ```loop = 0``` till ```loop < objCount - 1```. Shouldn't this be just ```objCount``` without the -1? This may be causing the list to be empty.

Comment: Same thing in the UpdateSpheres. Remove the -1 from the for loop.

Comment: @MajdOdeh Yes, they are not empty. Tried checking it using `Debug.Log` Thanks for the hint about the for loops, btw

Answer (score 1):

You do not create a number of spheres according to the code. You create just a single sphere and assign it to all your `Sphere` instances. To create and move your spheres:

- create `GameObject` object for every object instead of assigning the same object for each `Sphere` class instance
- use `.transform.position` of the created object, assigned to `Sphere` class instance to move the corresponding `GameObject` instance

Comment: Sorry to not include it on the post but the createSpheres method is called in a for loop and it's based on how many points are spawned. I'll update my question